# Remote database's records are blank

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am facing a WEIRD problem: I developed an app that requires a registration. 
But when it comes to save user's name, mail and password in a remote database (altervista) something goes wrong: when I try to view the user's table there are only blank records. NOT null, just blank. 
phpMyAdmin says that there are records, but they're blank, even if I made the registration via the app... 
No exception thrown, no network errors, nothing at all.

I can't tell if it's the android code that doesn't work or it's the php code or something else. 
I'm pasting here both of them so you can help me (or at least I hope you will)...

```
reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        { //reg is the registration button
        public void onClick(View v)             {   
            InputStream is;
            if(username.getText().length()== 0)
            {
                username.setText("Enter Username");
            }
            else if(password.getText().length()== 0)
            {
                password.setText("Enter Password");
            }
            else if(email.getText().length()==0)
            {
                email.setText("Enter email");
            }
            else{
                try{
                String a = username.getText().toString().trim();
                String b = password.getText().toString().trim();
                String c = email.getText().toString().trim();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tripleleon.altervista.org/register.php");
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> dati = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idutente",a));
                dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",b));
                dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", c));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dati,HTTP.UTF_8));


                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                username.setText("");
                password.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection error",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is the php code:

```
 <?php
     error_reporting(~E_NOTICE);
     //include('db.php');

    if($_GET['idutente'])
       {
       $fname=$_GET['idutente'];
       //echo $fname.'gytgy';
             }
    if($_GET['password'])
       {
       $fname=$_GET['password'];
       //echo $lname.'gytgy';
             }
       if($_GET['email'])
      {
        $email=$_GET['email'];
       //echo $email.'fgfdgdf';
          }
      $conn=mysql_connect("ip","user","password");
     if(!$conn)
          {
            die("could not connect". mysql_error());
              }
         mysql_select_db("my_tripleleon",$conn);


      //$name =$_POST['name'];
     $query="insert into info
       (idutente, password, email)values('".$idutente."','".$password."','".$email."')";

      $query1=mysql_query($query);
        if ($query1="")
     {echo "unsuccessfull";
          }
          else
        {
     echo"successfull";
        }
           ?>
```

EDIT: I'm not using threads or asynctasks. I'm simply (and not-so-correctly) modifying ThreadPolicies since I made the app for minSDK = 14...

Comment: run your php code in browser and print the query for run it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: it goes right. The browser tells me (what I told him to tell me in this cases) "succesfull". But, still, I have blank records o.O

Comment: you have wrote wrong condition in your code that is `if ($query1="")` `mysql_query`return true or false. Thats why you are getting success message. and i told that you need to echo the query on browser than run it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem a little stubborn but that IF checks if the query is null or not, hence if it says "succesfull" it means that the query is not null

Comment: No dear check this http://in3.php.net/mysql_query . return type of `mysql_query` function. it either true or false.

Comment: you are using assigning operator there `if($quer1="")` . should be `==`

Comment: ok I edited the code: if(!$quer1) and when I execute it the browser says "unsuccesfull" but I think it's normal since the php code receive data from my app. I'm going to try now and post the results here :)

Comment: Great..but don't think it make any changes in your o/p, if your query is not working

Comment: yeah I know. The weird fact is that in my previous app version it worked fine. I'm updating the app (only to use fragments) but I didn't touch the php code...

Comment: if the variables of query is coming properly than the PHP code will run fine...can't say about the app version :(

Comment: The PHP has a weird characteristic... you seem to be setting variables: $fname etc... and not $idutente etc... but then using the latter for the query.

Comment: @LeonGuerrero : A remark : you can use username.setError("Enter Username"); for better UI design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the values from the $_GET array while you should use the $_POST array since you are using an HttpPost and not a HttpGet. That's all. If you want you can use $_REQUEST so that you don't have to worry about these problems.

By the way...never compose sql query as you did taking for good the string passed by the user. You have to escape them ALWAYS!!!

Edit to explain better:

when you execute this code:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tripleleon.altervista.org/register.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dati = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idutente",a));
            dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",b));
            dati.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", c));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dati,HTTP.UTF_8));
```

what happens is that in the register.php script those values will be stored in the $_POST variable and not in the $_GET variable so...

this will NOT work, and you will get an empty value(and also a warning in php log):

```
$idutente=$_GET['idutente']
```

while this will work

```
$idutente=$_POST['idutente']
```

So try to get those values accessing the $_POST variable.

Comment: Hi Cristian (scrivo in inglese anche se siamo italiani xD). Yeah I know I'm probably violating some of the basic rules regarding security, but I'm now in a pre-alpha phase so security is something I will face in the next weeks... 
Talking about php, at the beginning of the code there are several $_GET because it gets values from the app and then posts the query to the relative table...

Comment: @LeonGuerrero I updated the answer to explain better what I meant ;)

Comment: I got what you're trying to say but the WEIRD thing is that I used THE SAME register.php for an older app and then everything was going fine. I'd be happy to discover that this is the real problem (so I won't have to recode everything xD). 
Btw I'll give your solution a try, hoping you're right :D

Comment: Tried your suggestion as soon as I could (since my pc has been unusable for two weeks) and that's it: you're right :D
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @LeonGuerrero You are welcome. Remember you can access them using $_REQUEST and so you don't have to care about what http method you use, I usually do this except in some rare cases.

Comment: yeah I know but I'm used to use a most specific code instead of a general one. It's a common problem among us developers xD

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this (the variable names are what have been changed):

```
if($_GET['idutente'])
   $idutente=$_GET['idutente'];

if($_GET['password'])
   $password=$_GET['password'];

if($_GET['email'])
   $email=$_GET['email']

$conn=mysql_connect("ip","user","password");
mysql_select_db("my_tripleleon",$conn);

$query="insert into info
   (`idutente`, `password`, `email`)values('".$idutente."','".$password."','".$email."')";
```

Another thing is:

```
if ($query1="")
```

Which should be:

```
if ($query1=="")
```

And finally, you should look into the mysqli family of functions to replace your "mysql_*" calls.

Comment: Probably this is the reason: I started this project two years ago so maybe in the meanwhile some functions have changed...